# Use of iTunes gift card credit

Tags: itunes

I have a $50 iTunes gift card credit. How can I use it for the App Store? When I try to purchase an app from the App Store, I am asked to enter a credit card number.  Can I transfer the $50 to the App Store account?

Comment: Do you already have an Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work...

Open iTunes

Just below the volume bar is your Apple ID.

Click on that and select Redeem. It will prompt for your Gift Card info..

Here's a little pic:

[image]